# Schedule Django Celery periodic tasks to run from time to other time

Tags: django, cron, celery, django-celery, periodic-task

How can I accomplish running Django Celery tasks to be running only from Mon to Friday and on those days only from 9am to 5pm EST?

`celery.py`

```
from celery.schedule import crontab


app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'compute-every-5-seconds': {
         'task': 'sum',
         'schedule': crontab(),
     },
  }
```

What parameters should I add to crontab() that it would run those days and between only those hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`celery.py`

```
from celery.schedule import crontab
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'compute-every-minute-mon-through-friday-9-to-5': {
         'task': 'sum',
         'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1',
hour='9-17', day_of_week='mon,tue,wed,thu,fri'),
     },
  }
```

`minute='*/1'` - runs every minute

`hour='9-17'` - runs 9am to 5pm

`day_of_week='mon,tue,wed,thu,fri'` - Monday through Friday

Most of these are available on the [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules) page, check it out!